# Getting duplicate JSON items while converting List to Dictionary

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am creating a JSON file by reading some data from a List of objects, converting it to nested Dictionaries and serializing the result.  The desired JSON format is as follows:

```
{
  "Employee1": {
    "YYY": {
      "StartRange": 11,
      "EndRange": 22
    }
  },
  "Employee2": {
    "XXX": {
      "StartRange": 24,
      "EndRange": 56
    }
  }
}
```

But I am getting this JSON output instead:

```
{
  "Employee1": {
    "YYY": {
      "StartRange": 11,
      "EndRange": 22
    },
    "XXX": {
      "StartRange": 11,
      "EndRange": 22
    }
  },
  "Employee2": {
    "YYY": {
      "StartRange": 24,
      "EndRange": 56
    },
    "XXX": {
      "StartRange": 24,
      "EndRange": 56
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
public class LabelData
{
    public int StartRange { get; set; }
    public int EndRange { get; set; }
}

public class ConfigInfo
{
    public string ParentGroup;
    public string Label;
    public int ID;
    public int StartRange;
    public int EndRange;
}

public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, LabelData>> GetData(List<ConfigInfo> configList)
{
    var labelData = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, LabelData>>();

    foreach (var listItem in configList)
    {
        labelData[listItem.ParentGroup] = configList.Distinct().ToDictionary(x => x.Label.ToString(), row => new LabelData()
        {
         StartRange = Convert.ToInt32(listItem.StartRange.ToString()),
         EndRange = Convert.ToInt32(listItem.EndRange.ToString())
        });
    }

    return labelData;
}

protected void createFile()
{
    List<ConfigInfo> configInfoList = new List<ConfigInfo>();

    ConfigInfo configInfo = new ConfigInfo();
    configInfo.ParentGroup = "Employee1";
    configInfo.StartRange = 11;
    configInfo.EndRange = 22;
    configInfo.Label = "YYY";
    configInfoList.Add(configInfo);

    configInfo = new ConfigInfo();
    configInfo.ParentGroup = "Employee2";
    configInfo.StartRange = 24;
    configInfo.EndRange = 56;
    configInfo.Label = "XXX";
    configInfoList.Add(configInfo);

    if (!File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw);

        Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, LabelData>> data = GetData(configInfoList);
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data,Formatting.Indented);
        sw.Write(json);
        sw.Close();
    }
}
```

I think the problem might be related to having the StartRange and EndRange in both the classes, but I don't know how to fix it.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand your requirements.  In the final desired output you want the Label, StartRange and EndRange for Employee1 to appear under Employee2 and you want Employee2's Label, StartRange and EndRange to appear under Employee1?  What happens if there are three employees in the list instead of 2?  What if there is only 1?

Comment: If there is one Employee the output will be

Comment: If there is one Employee the output will be {
  "Employee1": {
    "YYY": {
      "StartRange": 11,
      "EndRange": 22
    }
  }
} If there are three employees the output will be {
  "Employee1": {
    "YYY": {
      "StartRange": 11,
      "EndRange": 22
    }
  },
  "Employee2": {
    "YYY": {
      "StartRange": 24,
      "EndRange": 56
    }
  },
  "Employee3": 
    "AAA": {
      "StartRange": 56,
      "EndRange": 99
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this code in your `GetData` method:

```
var labelData = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, LabelData>>();

foreach (var listItem in configList)
{
    labelData[listItem.ParentGroup] = 
        configList.Distinct().ToDictionary(x => x.Label.ToString(), row => new LabelData()
    {
        StartRange = Convert.ToInt32(listItem.StartRange.ToString()),
        EndRange = Convert.ToInt32(listItem.EndRange.ToString())
    });
}
```

For each `ConfigInfo` item in the list, you are adding a `Dictionary` to the result containing the `Label` of *every item in the list* combined with the `StartRange` and `EndRange` of the current item.

I think what you really want is to group the items by `ParentGroup`, then create dictionaries for each group containing just the items in that group.  Replace the above code with the following and you should get the output you expect:

```
var labelData = configList
    .GroupBy(c => c.ParentGroup)
    .ToDictionary(
        g => g.Key,
        g => g.ToDictionary(
            c => c.Label,
            c => new LabelData
            {
                StartRange = c.StartRange,
                EndRange = c.EndRange
            }
        )
    );
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nzkj0h

As an aside, I think I would recommend renaming your `GetData` method to `TransformData`, since that is really what it is doing.